# Filter an array of objects with multiple elements with their values using javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object as below.

```
const data =
    [
     {id: 1, name: 'Peter',age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 2, name: 'Steve',age: 24, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 3, name: 'John',age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 4, name: 'Julie',age: 26, gender: 'Female'}
    ]
```

I want to dynamically filter the above array with multiple elements with their values using javascript or lodash. If i add more elements to the object and try to filter with the same, the code should work fine. I'm expecting to pass the elements which needs to be filtered and the corresponding values, from an object as below.

```
const filter = {'name':'e','gender':'mal'}
```

Expected Output:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Peter',age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
         {id: 2, name: 'Steve',age: 24, gender: 'Male'},
         {id: 4, name: 'Julie',age: 26, gender: 'Female'}]
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the filter you have used in the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Object.entries to separate the keys and values from the filter object, find the value by using the key and lowerCase that value since you don't differentiate between uppercase and lowercase letters

```js
const data =
    [
     {id: 1, name: 'Peter',age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 2, name: 'Steve',age: 24, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 3, name: 'John',age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 4, name: 'Julie',age: 26, gender: 'Female'}
    ]

const filter = {
  'name': 'e',
  'gender': 'mal'
}


const result = data.filter(x => Object.entries(filter)
  .every(([key, val]) => x[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(val)))
  
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter by using the entries and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for using all filters or [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for having only one filter property of the object.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Peter', age: 21, gender: 'Male' }, { id: 2, name: 'Steve', age: 24, gender: 'Male' }, { id: 3, name: 'John', age: 21, gender: 'Male' }, { id: 4, name: 'Julie', age: 26, gender: 'Female' }],
    filter = { name: 'Pe', gender: 'Mal' },
    filters = Object.entries(filter),
    result1 = data.filter(o => filters.every(([k, v]) => o[k].includes(v))),
    result2 = data.filter(o => filters.some(([k, v]) => o[k].includes(v)));

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```